# Multiple checkbox shows only one

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to display 3 checkboxes:

```
var DescCheck = new Ext.form.Checkbox({
                      fieldLabel: 'Description of service : <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); padding-left: 2px;">*</span>',
                      width : 600,
                      labelSeparator : '',
                      items: [
                          {boxLabel: 'Direct', name: 'Direct', inputValue: 'Direct'},
                          {boxLabel: 'Fixed-day', name: 'day', inputValue: 'Fixed'},
                          {boxLabel: 'Weekly', name: 'Weekly', inputValue: 'Weekly'}
                        ]
});
```

This form.Checkbox is in a FieldSet (purely esthetic) which is in a Ext.FormPanel.

This is what happens : 
[image: checkbox]

Only one checkbox is displayed, without any label. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `Checkbox`, when it looks like what you want is a `CheckboxGroup`.  For v4.2.1, here are the docs for this: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup

```
var descCheck = new Ext.form.CheckboxGroup({
    ...
    items: [
        {boxLabel: 'Direct', name: 'Direct', inputValue: 'Direct'},
        {boxLabel: 'Fixed-day', name: 'day', inputValue: 'Fixed'},
        {boxLabel: 'Weekly', name: 'Weekly', inputValue: 'Weekly'}
    ]
});
```

One other thing to note, you should always name your variables starting with a lowercase letter (`descCheck` instead of `DescCheck`).